# Click inside table not working with Selenium ide recording

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am new to Selenium.

I am trying to record an angularjs based web site.

I want to record a click done inside the table.

Whenever i try to perform this with selenium ide chrome it is just hanging.

But it is working fine if i do it normally.

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Please do share the website url and also the code with which you're trying to perform the click. It'll help to better understand where you're making mistake.

Comment: unforuntely the website is behind a firewall and hence cannot be checked here...i am using selenium ide in chrome to perform the click

Comment: can you post any screenshot for better understanding?

Comment: @saurav I believe you can share your code you have tried and copy HTML of table you are trying to interact with. It is not possible to debug issue without seeing HTML source code.